# Getting new BigNumber() not a number: [object, object] error

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am getting a BigNumber() error from the standard token function balanceOf(). The function returns uint256, but it seems like it's returning an array of objects. Here is my javascript testing in Truffle:

```
      return tokFactory.createTok(100000,"tok",1,"tok",{from: accounts[0]}).then(function(txHash) { 
      tokFactory.getTokenAddress.call().then(function(tokenAddress) { 
      tok = Tok.at(tokenAddress);
      }).then(function() { 
    tok.balanceOf.call(tokFactory).then(function(balance) {
  assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 100000, "100000 wasn't in the first   account");
});
  });
      });
```

Solidity function:

```
function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
}
```

Comment: "The function returns uint256, but it seems like it's returning an array of objects". What makes you think this? Also, try replacing `tok.balanceOf.call(tokFactory.address)`

Comment: Ok passing in the tokFactory address fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Facing the same error. i am trying this return KNTInstance.balanceOf.call(accounts[0], {from: accounts[0]});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the mistake is in

```
 tok.balanceOf.call(tokFactory).then(function(balance)
```

you should call

```
tok.balanceOf.call(tokFactory.address)
```

get it? you should pass the uint256 address of the contract not it's object rappresentation